# SharePoint file size limit

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, iis, file, upload

I've tried many tutorials online on how to increase the upload file size for a SharePoint document library with no luck.

Any ideas on how to increase the limit of file upload to a document library?

I've tried:

http://spsstuff.blogspot.com/2006/03/how-to-change-maximum-file-upload-size.html
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29380049/50mb-upload-limit--help.aspx
http://www.msexperts.org/blogs/mark/archive/2008/10/23/increasing-the-maximum-upload-limit-on-a-sharepoint-site.aspx

Comment: Are you trying to do this for an individual document library or for the entire web application? As far as i know, it can only be set in Central Administration per Web Application.

Comment: When you say they didn't work, what happened?
Did any errors appear in the SP Logs? Was an error message shown in the UI when you tried to update, or did it *seem* to work, and then just NOT increase the upload?

Comment: The maximum file size is currently the default 50mb.

Comment: I'm looking into doing this for the entire web application.

Comment: From MSDN? - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925083

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I followed the 1st instruction from the 2nd link you provided:

> 1. In SharePoint 3.0 Central Administration, Application Management
>      tab, and Web application general
>      settings configure the Maximum upload
>      size to a maximum of 2047 MB.

and it worked fine.

Are you sure that you selected **appropriate Web application** when changing the maximum upload size?

[image: changing the selected Web Application]

Comment: Is there any hard limit, beyond which cannot be increased? Or is that the 2047MB?

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the limit in code

```
SPWebApplication oWebApplication = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri("http://MyServer:989"));

oWebApplication.MaximumFileSize = 2000;

oWebApplication.Update();
```

(example taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.aspx))

It will probably require admin credentials ([SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx) should handle this). 
Of course I'd rather use the configuration change method mentioned above by @Marek Grzenkowicz